# How to find the area of a spherical equilateral triangle?

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose an equilateral triangle is drawn on the surface of the earth (considered to be an exact sphere). Length of each side of the triangle is $L = 1$ km. The radius of the earth is $R = 6400$ km. How do you calculate the area of the triangle?

**Is there any way to find the area of the triangle from the metric of the space, which is given by, in this case,**

$ds^2 = R^2 \left( d\theta^2 + \sin^2 \theta \hspace{1mm} d\phi^2  \right)$.

There is a relation between the angles ($\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$) of the triangle on a surface with positive curvature, which is given by,

$\alpha + \beta + \gamma = \pi + \frac{A}{R^2}$

where, $A$ is the area of the triangle, $R$ is the radius of curvature of the surface and the angles are in radian. If we can find $A$, we can calculate the sum of the angles of a triangle on a curved surface.

Comment: I think this a maths question rather than a physics question.

Comment: You can always scale things to keep the constant unity.

Answer (score 1):

Just like in Euclidean geometry, there exists a [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines) in spherical geometry, for triangles on a unit sphere:
$$
\cos a = \cos b\cos c + \sin b\sin c\cos\alpha\\
\cos b = \cos c\cos a + \sin c\sin a\cos\beta\\
\cos c = \cos a\cos b + \sin a\sin b\cos\gamma
$$
Note that the 'sides' $a,b,c$ of a spherical triangle are also angles. In your case, $a=b=c=L/R$ (in radians), from which you can calculate $\alpha=\beta=\gamma$, and subsequently the area.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the triangle is situated at the North Pole so that the corners are at $(\theta,\phi) = (0,0), (\theta_T,0)$ and $(\theta_T,\phi_T)$. From the metric $\mathrm d s^2 = g_{ij}\mathrm d x^i \mathrm d x^j = R^2(\mathrm d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta\mathrm d\phi^2)$ it is clear that we must have $\theta_T = \frac{L}{R}$ and $\phi_T=\frac{L}{R\sin\theta_T}$. Then the area can be calculated in the usual manner on a curved manifold

$$
 A = \int_{\mathrm{triangle}}\mathrm{d}^2x \sqrt{|\mathrm{det}\: g|} = R^2\int_0^{\phi_T}\mathrm{d}\phi\int_0^{\theta_T}\mathrm{d}\theta\sin\theta = \frac{RL}{\sin\frac{L}{R}}\left(1-\cos\frac{L}{R}\right) \simeq \frac{L^2}{2}\left[1+\frac{1}{12}\left(\frac{L}{R}\right)^2 + \mathcal O\left(\frac{L^4}{R^4}\right)\right].
$$